# Link error implementing CRC 32 on a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am trying to implement checksum (CRC32) for my project.

I am getting the following Link error when I try to build the project:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Crc32::Crc32(void)" (??0Crc32@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_configfile_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_configfile_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)
```

I added the class file to do crc32, which is implemented as follows.

`CRC32.h` :

```
#ifndef CRC32_H
#define CRC32_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QString>
#include <QMap>


class Crc32
{
private:
    quint32 crc_table[256];
    QMap<int, quint32> instances;

public:
    Crc32();

    quint32 calculateFromFile(QString filename);

    void initInstance(int i);
    void pushData(int i, char *data, int len);
    quint32 releaseInstance(int i);
};

#endif // CRC32_H
```

and `CRC32.cpp` is:

```
#include "crc32.h"

#include <QFile>

Crc32::Crc32()
{
    quint32 crc;

    // initialize CRC table
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        crc = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xEDB88320UL : crc >> 1;

        crc_table[i] = crc;
    }
}

quint32 Crc32::calculateFromFile(QString filename)
{
    quint32 crc;
    QFile file;

    char buffer[16000];
    int len, i;

    crc = 0xFFFFFFFFUL;

    file.setFileName(filename);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        while (!file.atEnd())
        {
            len = file.read(buffer, 16000);
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
                crc = crc_table[(crc ^ buffer[i]) & 0xFF] ^ (crc >> 8);
        }

        file.close();
    }

    return crc ^ 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
}

void Crc32::initInstance(int i)
{
    instances[i] = 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
}

void Crc32::pushData(int i, char *data, int len)
{
    quint32 crc = instances[i];
    if (crc)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            crc = crc_table[(crc ^ data[j]) & 0xFF] ^ (crc >> 8);

        instances[i] = crc;
    }
}

quint32 Crc32::releaseInstance(int i)
{
    quint32 crc32 = instances[i];
    if (crc32) {
        instances.remove(i);
        return crc32 ^ 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and here is how I call crc32 on my MainWindow:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_configfile_clicked()
{

    QString txtfilename = "demoFES_1";
    QString configFileName = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/data/config_file/"+txtfilename+".txt";


    Crc32 crc1; // crc32 instance
    qDebug()<<"CRC32 from file: "<<crc1.calculateFromFile(configFileName);   

}
```

Any idea what might be the source of the link error?

Comment: My guess is `CRC32.cpp` was not added to your `.pro` as a source file.

Comment: Here is the documentation related to my comment above: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-project-files.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-project-files.html)